# How many hours of Meditation in single sitting during Vipassana?

Tags: vipassana, meditation-practicalities, buddha

I was wondering its not much difficult to sit for one hour in meditation, but i want to know in Vipassana 10 days course, How long one will have to meditate, i mean do they do split meditation of 1 hour several times a day or 3-4 hours of continuous meditation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each session is about 1 hour in courses organised in groups. E.g.

```
4:00 am             Morning wake-up bell
4:30-6:30 am        Meditate in the hall or in your room
6:30-8:00 am        Breakfast break
8:00-9:00 am        Group meditation in the hall
9:00-11:00 am       Meditate in the hall or in your room according to the teacher's instructions
11:00-12:00 noon    Lunch break
12noon-1:00 pm      Rest and interviews with the teacher
1:00-2:30 pm        Meditate in the hall or in your room
2:30-3:30 pm        Group meditation in the hall
3:30-5:00 pm        Meditate in the hall or in your own room according to the teacher's instructions
5:00-6:00 pm        Tea break
6:00-7:00 pm        Group meditation in the hall
7:00-8:15 pm        Teacher's Discourse in the hall
8:15-9:00 pm        Group meditation in the hall
9:00-9:30 pm        Question time in the hall
9:30 pm             Retire to your own room--Lights out
```

Source: https://www.dhamma.org/en/about/code

```
4:00 am          Wake up
4:30             Meditation in hall
5:30             Morning discourse
6:30 - 8:00      Breakfast and rest
8:00 - 9:00      Group meditation in hall (for all)
9:30             Individual instruction (for all)
11:00 - 1:00 pm  Lunch and rest
1:00 - 1:45      Meditation
2:00 - 3:00      Group meditation in hall (for all)
3:30 - 5:00      Meditation, and interviews for new students
5:00 - 6:00      Tea and rest
6:00             Evening discourse
7:30 - 8:30      Group meditation in hall (for all)
9:00             Retire
```

Source: http://www.internationalmeditationcentre.org/uk/guidelines.html

```
MORNING SESSION

03.30 – 04.00 a.m.                 –         Wake-up / Dress-up

04.00 – 05.00 a.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

05.00 – 06.30 a.m.                 –         Sitting Meditation

06.30 – 08.15 a.m.                 –         Breakfast dana, cleaning common areas, toilets and dorms etc.

08.15 – 09.15 a.m.                 –         Sitting Meditation

09.15 – 10.15 a.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

10.15 – 11.15 a.m.                 –         Sitting Meditation

11.15 – 12.00 p.m.                 –         Lunch Daana



AFTERNOON SESSION

12.00 – 01.00 p.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

01.00 – 02.00 p.m.                 –         Q&A / Dhamma Discussion (Every Day)

02.00 – 03.00 p.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

03.00 – 04.00 p.m.                 –         Sitting Meditation (Except the Last Day)

04.00 – 05.00 p.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

05.00 – 06.30 p.m.                 –         Dhamma Talk (Except the Last Day)

06.30 – 07.00 p.m.                 –         Mindfullness Gilanpasa (Tea) Break

07.00 – 08.00 p.m.                 –         Walking Meditation

08.00 – 09.00 p.m.                 –         Sitting Meditation

09.00 p.m.                         –         End of Day’s Program

All the access doors to the meditation premises should be closed and the lights should be turned off by 10.00 p.m.
```

Source: http://www.nissarana.lk/meditate-with-us/retreat-timetable/

If you are tailoring a private course for yourself maybe you can have longer sessions.

The time tables are set so both new and old students can meditate in reasonable comfort. There is nothing to worry about the time of the session lengths as many meditators do not find this an issue.